# Events in Android OS/iOS /debian linux (on click of Enter key)

Tags: javascript, android, ios, event-handling, debian

How can we detect enter key press event using JavaScript?
I want to restrict the enter key press event on a text box in various platforms such as Android OS, iOS, Debian Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The enter key is 13. If you have an event listener then you can listen for when the key is pressed like so:

```
document.body.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  if(event.keyCode == 13)
    alert("You hit the enter key");
})
```

Comment: Sorry I am not sure, I work mostly in web development

Answer (score 0):

```
window.addEventListener('keyDown', function(e){
    alert(e.keyCode);
});
```

Press the Enter Key, and the key code should come up in an alert. Hope it works

Comment: will it work for mobile android,iOS devices or debian linux os? @ theteachersofthing

Comment: I Don't know. I'm not an Android or Linux developer. But I think it should.